# SharedElement transition not working from fragment contains a recyclerview to another fragment using the new Navigation architecture component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have an android app that holds 2 fragment, the first fragment holding a recyclerview that shows a list of contacts here is the code of the first fragment

```
public class NotesFragment extends Fragment implements ContactsAdapter.OnContactClicked {


    public NotesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        RecyclerView rvContacts = view.findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));

        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>(){{
            add(new Contact(1,"Antoine El Murr"));
            add(new Contact(2,"Joelle Abou Chakra"));
            add(new Contact(3,"Michel Jebran"));
            add(new Contact(4,"Charlie Abou Moussa"));
            add(new Contact(5,"Edward Salameh"));
            add(new Contact(6,"Makram Merdass"));
            add(new Contact(7,"Sami Abou Jaoudeh"));
            add(new Contact(8,"Elie Nassif"));
            add(new Contact(9,"Samer Abou Samra"));
            add(new Contact(10,"Fady Ammoury"));
            add(new Contact(11,"Dany Fahed"));
            add(new Contact(12,"Mariana Haddad"));
            add(new Contact(13,"Mohamad Restom"));
        }};

        ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);
        adapter.setOnContactClicked(this);
        rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onContactClicked(int position, Contact contact, View holderView) {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(holderView);
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putParcelable("contact", contact);
        FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                .addSharedElement(holderView.findViewById(R.id.tvIcon), ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holderView.findViewById(R.id.tvIcon)))
                .addSharedElement(holderView.findViewById(R.id.tvName), ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holderView.findViewById(R.id.tvName)))
                .build();
        navController.navigate(R.id.ContactToDetails, arguments, null, extras);
    }
}
```

I am using the android jetpack Navigation component
In the layout file of the elements of the recyclerview I am setting the transition name of each element as shown below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIcon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:transitionName="icon"
        tools:text="A" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvIcon"
        android:transitionName="name"
        tools:text="Antoine El Murr" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And created an interface in my adapter that trigger a function on contact clicked

In my second fragment, I have set the transition name in my xml layout as shown below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ContactDetailsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIcon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="A"
        android:transitionName="icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvIcon"
        tools:text="Antoine El Murr"
        android:transitionName="name"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And set in onCreate the enter transition but it's not working:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
    }
```

Please help, I have surfed the internet for a solution but with no luck all the examples are on the old navigation system, and the new examples are how to use SharedElements from a fragment to another fragment, but not from a recyclerview, and the documentation on the android website is poor and small and not covering all the steps to achieve this transition with the new navigation component

Answer (score 1):

I have figure out the problem, instead of putting the transition name inside xml element, put it in the ViewHolder (or Adapter) and give each element in the recycle view a unique transition name

Example: 
Element at position 0 -> transition name = "image_view_transition_0" 
Element at position 1 -> transition name = "image_view_transition_1"

So android know which element to animate, if all element has same transition name it will get confused of which element is going to animate

Comment: Hey, but you also have to name the transition in the element of the other fragment. How do you name it? Because in the recyclerview every element will have a different transition name

Comment: You have to pass the transition name of each element you want to transition through arguments and set the passed transition names to the corresponding elements

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have matching `transitionName(s)` between your layouts.

```xml
android:transitionName="YOUR_TRANSITION_NAME"
```

Then make sure to pass the shared view instance like (you can also use safeArgs):

```
some_view.setOnClickListener{
  val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(
    yourSharedViewInstance to "YOUR_TRANSITION_NAME"
  )
  findNavController().navigate(R.id.your_destination_action, null, null, extras)
}
```

Then at your destination

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move /* or any other transition you want to use */)
}
```

And that should be it :)

Comment: As listed in my question, I have matching transitionName in my layouts and I am passing the share view instance: `FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                .addSharedElement(tvIcon, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(tvIcon))
                .addSharedElement(tvName, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(tvName))
                .build();
        navController.navigate(R.id.ContactToDetails, arguments, null, extras);` But it's not working

Comment: When I tried outside recyclerview it's working fine but inside recyclerview it's not working